# How to include p-values in heatpmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I generated a correlation heatmap of 4 variables using seaborn. In each cell of the heatmap, I would like to include both the correlation and the p-value associated with the correlation. Ideally, the p-value should be on a new line and in brackets. I am trying to use the annot argument for displaying both the correlation and p-value in the heatmap. However, I am getting the error below and I am not sure how to fix it.
---> 12 corr_matrix, pvalues = data.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x, y))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I really would appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you in advance for your time.

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# Generate a synthetic dataset of 4 variables
np.random.seed(42)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# Calculate the correlation matrix and p-values
corr_matrix, pvalues = data.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x, y))

# Generate the heatmap of the correlation matrix
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr_matrix, dtype=bool))
sns.set(style='white')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.heatmap(corr_matrix, annot=True, fmt='.2f', cmap='coolwarm', mask=mask, cbar_kws={'shrink': 0.8},
            ax=ax, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0)
for i in range(corr_matrix.shape[0]):
    for j in range(corr_matrix.shape[1]):
        if i >= j:
            continue
        value = '{:.2f}\n(p={:.2e})'.format(corr_matrix.iloc[i, j], pvalues.iloc[i, j])
        ax.text(j+0.5, i+0.5, value, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=10, color='white')
plt.title('Correlation Heatmap')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a bit to step through the code and get familiar with what you were trying to do. But I think this is what you're looking for.

You were very, very close. Basically what I did is break it into two parts.

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# Calculate the correlation matrix using Pearson correlation coefficients
corr_matrix = data.corr(method='pearson')

# Calculate the p-values for the correlation coefficients
pvalues = round(data.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x, y)[1]), 4)

# Generate the heatmap of the correlation matrix
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr_matrix, dtype=bool))
sns.set(style='white')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.heatmap(corr_matrix, annot=True, fmt='.2f', cmap='coolwarm', mask=mask, cbar_kws={'shrink': 0.8},
            ax=ax, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0)

# Update the heatmap labels with correlation coefficients and p-values
for i in range(corr_matrix.shape[0]):
    for j in range(corr_matrix.shape[1]):
        if i >= j:
            continue
        corr = '{:f}'.format(corr_matrix.iloc[i, j]),
        pval = pvalues.iloc[i, j]
        ax.text(j+0.5, i+0.5, corr, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=10, color='white')
        ax.text(i+0.5, j+0.6, pval, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=10, color='green')

plt.title('Correlation Heatmap')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]